# UnicodeDecodeError with an unicode variable

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using an unicode variable and replacing some characters, but when I try to process a certain value it raises an error of UnicodeDecodeError, when I have set at the beginning of python's file the coding.

I tried this coding: iso-8859-15, cp1251,and I took a look to this but doesn't when the variable's value contains this character: `

At the terminal this works:

```
a='Don\xb4t dream it\xb4s over'
a = a.replace("\xb4","'")
print a
output: Don't dream it's over
```

Why does it work in the terminal but not in my python's file?.

Comment: Can you post your code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working for me.  Here's what I have done:

1. Copy the following code to a file, and name it as `test.py`

   ```
   a='Don\xb4t dream it\xb4s over'
   a = a.replace("\xb4","'")
   print a
   ```
2. Run test.py `python ./test.py`, and here's the output

   ```
   Don't dream it's over
   ```
3. My python version is Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode from the proper code page into Unicode. Then if you need it in another code page (such as UTF-8) you can re-encode it. WHen you use `print` Python will try to encode it to the code page of your terminal automatically.

```
>>> a = a.decode('iso-8859-1')
>>> print a
Don´t dream it´s over
```

Edit: Trying to decipher the actual question is difficult. Perhaps you're trying to read the text from a file and that's what's not working? Again it's important to know the encoding of the file. Many modern files use UTF-8 encoding.

```
a = f.readline()
a = a.decode('utf-8')
print a
```